# Shortcuts doesn't work with notify-osd stopped

Tags: shortcut-keys, notify-osd

Whenever I stop `notify-osd` using

```
pkill -SIGSTOP notify-osd
```

all shortcuts doesn't work anymore (or at least doesn't work well).
I mean, sometimes for random periods of time they works well. 
Other times it seems that they doesn't work: I press the mute button and nothing happens. Then, some minutes later, all the shortcuts are invoked one after another and finally the audio is muted.

This strange behaviour only occurs when I `SIGSTOP` the process, while if I'm `SIGKILL` it all works normally.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Just a guess, but based on your question I would say it happens because you use the command `pkill -SIGSTOP notify-osd`. Does everything work as expected if you don't do that?

Comment: Obv yes, but the point is that `notify-osd` should only disable notifications, not shortcuts (at least I think).

Comment: What happens if you prevent it from starting instead of killing it? Have you taken note of the system load when you observe this unwanted behaviour? Can you provide any further information that might help us understand the root cause of your problem? Any errors in syslog or dmesg that seem relevant? Please [edit] your question to provide any further information that may help us help you! Thank you! Based on what little information you've given me all I could say is your system load is too high, everything gets put on the stack and when it finally catches up you receive the behaviour reported.

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks for your time. Well, all I know until now is that this strange behaviour occurs only when I SIGSTOP the process, while if I'm SIGKILL it all works normally.

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://superuser.com/questions/594508/whats-the-difference-between-sigkill-and-sigstop also http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ucs.cam.ac.uk%2Fdocs%2Fcourse-notes%2Funix-courses%2FBuilding%2Ffiles%2Fsignals.pdf&ei=Z24qVbzFG8fToAT9mICQCw&usg=AFQjCNGRiyEvqIHXuvpX3a-MAnLsFQQZag&sig2=WId_ZaxQfA4nSeXnZp4Zjg&bvm=bv.90491159,d.cGU this may also provide some insight: http://blogofsiva.blogspot.com/2012/06/why-sigkill-and-sigstop-cannot-be.html

Comment: @ElderGeek thanks again. So, could it be a bug? I don't know, to me it seems that when I `pkill -SIGSTOP notify-osd` and then press any combination key which involves a notification, the signal is send to `notify-osd` first. At this point, because it is suspended, the combination is "blocked" without executing. Then, after some period of time, `notify-osd` decides to let it go and it is executed.
It is not a normal behavior since any other process that usuall involves a notification (e.g. a mail reception from `thunderbird` process) is immediately executed

Answer (score 1):

When you send the unstoppable SIGSTOP signal, the program is placed in a paused state with the expectation that a SIGCONT signal will be received, I believe what you are seeing is by design.

"The only circumstances in which an unstoppable signal may be deferred is if the process is in IO wait, or stuck in kernel space. Then it’s just deferred, and will be dispatched once the process leaves kernel space."

Sources:

https://superuser.com/questions/594508/whats-the-difference-between-sigkill-and-sigstop

http://blogofsiva.blogspot.com/2012/06/why-sigkill-and-sigstop-cannot-be.html

http://www.ucs.cam.ac.uk/docs/course-notes/unix-courses/Building/files/signals.pdf